# Could Not Find Tilt Heroku Deploy

Tags: heroku

I'm getting on deploys after upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0:

```
Could not find tilt-1.3.5 in any of the sources
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Encountered the same problem using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12 after upgrading from 3.2.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem after upgrade rails too. So I modified Gemfile.lock to use tilt 1.3.3 instead of tilt 1.3.5. Now it works for me.

Gemfile.lock

```
tilt (1.3.5)
```

-->

```
tilt (1.3.3)
```

Comment: Note: tilt 1.3.4 also fixes the issue.

Comment: Do not modify `Gemfile.lock`. Add to your `Gemfile`: `gem "tilt", "1.3.4"`.

Comment: Tricon, can you explain why? If I do it in the Gemfile.lock then it can be overridden later with a simple bundle update, whereas if I do it in the Gemfile it's there until I remember to remove the version from the Gemfile.

Comment: Don't forget to commit your changes to gemfile and gemfile.lock before pushing!

Comment: i'd guess heroku cached metadata from rubygems.org and not having 1.3.5 in that cache?

Answer (score 2):

Why is this happening? I also had to add to the Gemfile:

```
gem "tilt", "1.3.4"
```